# How to troubleshoot CSS in a large style sheet?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, background-color

I am trying to modify the CSS in a Wordpress plugin I need to use. The stylesheet (learnpress.css) is over 2000 lines long, so understanding it is a challenge; but what I'm trying to do is pretty simple -- change the background color of a certain class.

The code is at https://tgtau.rickcasey.net/courses/the-great-turning-you/, but when I change the background color of the section-content class in Chrome's developer tools, nothing happens:
[image]

Can anyone point out how I can find out what other css styles are overriding this? Other posts only hint at CSS being difficult to diagnose how inheritance and precedence work, so I'm hoping there are some techniques in chrome-dev-tools on how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is set in the `li` elements themselves, so no matter what you set your `ul` background to, it won't be visible as the contained `li` elements are not transparent (solid white).

When debugging these cases, remember that every element can have its own background color, and containers can auto-size to their contents. You can also override the css on the `li` elements to make them transparent so that your `ul` background is visible.

Comment: Thanks; I learned that backgrounds don't inherit, so the tip about making the li element background transparent was the light bulb moment for me.